# Using logarithmic differentiation, find $y'$. Am I correct?

Tags: derivatives

Using logarithmic differentiation, find $y'$.

$$y=\ln x^{\cos(x)} \space (x>1)$$

I solved and here is my answer:

> $$y'=(\ln x)^{\cos(x)}(\cfrac{\cos(x)}{x\ln x}-\sin x\ln(\ln x)) $$

But I don't understand what is $(x>1)$ use for?

Or am I missed something?

Comment: Note that $\ln(x)$ is negative for $x<1$ and $\cos(x)$ is not an integer for the same range, so $\ln(x)^\cos(x)$ makes no sense for $x<1$.

Comment: Then, is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You should probably adjust your original equation to read $$(\ln(x))^{\cos(x)}.$$ The way it's written is a bit ambiguous and you fixed it down below anyway.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Okay.